# Saving to "/" on Apache server w/CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

This seems like a basic question, but it's stumping me. I have CodeIgniter installed, and I've got a model that manipulates and saves XMLs. My problem is when trying to save it to "/" I get a "Permission denied" PHP error. I need to save them to a separate directory relatively, but I'm not sure where exactly "/" is located on the server. Is it in the "/www" of Apache, or root of the whole server? Once I know this I should be able to navigate to the correct directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` is the root directory. The starting point of your directory structure. This is where the Linux system begins. Every other file and directory on your system is under the root directory. Usually the root directory contains only sub-directories, so it's a bad idea to store single files directly under root.

Try specifying the complete path in your application.

Example: `/home/user/public_html/yourApplicationFolder/`

Or specify a relative path:

Example: `../somePath/`.

[This](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm) article could be helpful.

Comment: thank you! I wasn't trying to save in root, just wasn't sure how to navigate from there to the directory I wanted. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To get the filesystem path to the document root just use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];`